# Generate HTML using XSLT from XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to generate HTML from XML via XSLT
I just posted 2 sample header but I want dynamic header

---

```
<PAP>
    <headers>
        <header>a1</header>
        <header>a2</header>
        <header>a3</header>
    </headers>
    <headers>
        <header>b1</header>
        <header>b2</header>
        <header>b3</header>
    </headers>
    <Others>
        <header>a1</header>
        <header>a2</header>
        <header>a3</header>
    </others>

    <entries>
        <entry id="1">
            <a1>Sample1</a1>
            <a2>1000</a2>
            <a3>1000</a3>
        </entry>
        <entry id="2">
            <b1>Sample2</b1>
            <b2>2000</b2>
            <b3>2000</b3>
        </entry>
</PAP>
```

---

---

First Table

```
a1      a2  a3
Sample1 1000    1000
```

Second Table

```
b1      b2  b3
Sample1 1000    1000
```

---

---

```
a1      a2  a3  b1  b2  b3
Sample1 1000    1000    2000    2000    2000
```

---

---

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="k1" match="entry/*" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', local-    name())"/>
<xsl:variable name="headers" select="/REPORT/PAP/headers/header"/>
<xsl:variable name="parameter" select="/REPORT/PAP/PARAMETER"/>

<xsl:template match="PAP">
<xsl:apply-templates select="entries"/>
</xsl:template>


          <xsl:template match="entries">
            <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table class="bed">
                <thead id="columns">
                  <tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$headers" mode="header"/>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              </body>
            </html>
          </xsl:template>

          <xsl:template match="header" mode="header">
            <th style="width:100px">
              <xsl:value-of select="./@num"/>
            </th>
          </xsl:template>

          <xsl:template match="entry">
            <tr>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="$headers">
                <xsl:with-param name="entry" select="current()"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
            </tr>
          </xsl:template>

          <xsl:template match="header">
            <xsl:param name="entry"/>
               <td align="left" style="padding-left:0px;">
                 <xsl:value-of select="key('k1', concat(generate-id($entry), '|', .))"/>
               </td>
          </xsl:template>

        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit your question to show the actual HTML you are trying to output, rather than just a visual representation? Thanks!

Comment: What is `REPORT` doing in `select="/REPORT/PAP/headers/header"`?